# How to make an OnCollision reset level script?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I am making a game and I want to make a script that if a player collides with the resetting object the scene will reset/reload.

Comment: Have you actually tried something before asking this quesiton?

Answer (score 2):

Code should be like:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
 if(other.tag == "setting_object_tag")
 {
  Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
 }
}
```

Make the colliding object as trigger and not using gravity as it will not effect surroundings. `Application.loadedLevel` is the current scene.

Comment: What seems to be problem?

Comment: I dont remember lol!

Comment: @HearPcGaming It is not hard to reevaluate the process and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of (**depricated**)

```
Application.Load(Application.loadedLevel);
```

use

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneBuildIndex);
```

or

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
```

You can also get current active `Scene`with `SceneManager.GetActiveScene()`.

Comment: Thank you! Application.loadlevel(Application.loadlevel) Didn't worked for me.I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that the code suggested by SP is only if the collision is set to trigger(it doesn't actually stop a rigidbody, it just triggers when the object is in it). if it isn't a trigger, then change

```
OnTriggerEnter
```

to

```
OnCollisionEnter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Respawn)
{
    if (Respawn.tag.Equals("Respawn"))

    {
        StartCoroutine("ReloadScene");
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }
}


IEnumerator ReloadScene()
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.5f);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");


}
```

and tag object at respawn TAG